# Initialize a Point2D in List<>

Tags: java, list, sorting, 2d, points

If I have a simple List< Point2D > declared.

Example:

```
List<Point2D> listOfPoints;

/* What I tried */
Point2D point1;
listOfPoints.add(point1);
```

But, how does one initialize `point1` so that I can have a coordinate of let's say `(3,2)`?

Comment: Refer to the above link... it will give you all the tools you need to understand this error and fix it for all the future times you're going to have that exception...

Comment: Constructing an object is an extremely basic task. Spend a little time on research before expecting people to spend their time to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create an instance of `Point2D`. Right now, you are adding `null` to your `listOfPoints`. Plus, `listOfPoints` is not initialized, so your code would generate a `NullPointerException`. Try this instead:

```
List<Point2D> listOfPoints = new ArrayList<>(); // or another List implementation class

Point2D point1 = new Point2D.Float(3, 2); // or perhaps Point2D.Double
listOfPoints.add(point1);
```

Also, once you have a `Point2D.Float` or `Point2D.Double` object, you can set the coordinates explicitly, either by assigning directly to the `x` and `y` fields or by calling `setLocation()` and passing the coordinates.

Comment: Ah. I see what what you are doing. Thank you very much, kind sir!

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
Point2D point1 = new Point2D.Double(3, 2);
```

or

```
Point2D point1 = new Point2D.Float(3, 2);
```

You will also want to initialise your List, e.g.

```
List<Point2D> listOfPoints = new ArrayList<>();
listOfPoints.add(point1);
```

Simply doing `new Point2D(3, 2)` will not work as Point2D is abstract.